# How to determine the type of an element with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using `ng-model`, can we determine the type of an element?

*Example:* I want to know whether this is a dropdown or a checkbox...

**HTML**

```
<select multiple ng-model='p.color'>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
myctrl.controller('ctrl_new', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
  $scope.create = function () {
    console.log($scope.p['color']);
  }
}
```

Comment: you can do it with the help of hasClass() of jquery

Comment: what is the situation you need to determine the type ?

Comment: On different elemenent types i need to produuce diffeenet json structures

Comment: Can't you create a property in the object to keep the element type ?

Comment: yes i can create it but on submit how will i retreve it back

Answer (score 0):

If I get you well, angular.element may help you.

Angular.element works just like JQuery. So, if you are using jquery fine if not
it will use jqLite.

```
<select multiple id='p.color'>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

myctrl.controller('ctrl_new', ['$scope',function ($scope){
  $scope.create = function ()
  {
          var element = angular.element('#p.color');
              console.log(element.type);
  }
}
```

Comment: can we do it using ng-model and without using id

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this. Create a directive, bind "click" to the elements and then console log it. Run this and check your browser console. Something like this:

```
<div checker id="container">
    <select multiple ng-model='p.color'>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>

app.directive('checker', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("click", function (event) {
                console.log(event.target);
            });
        };
    });
```

Comment: can we do it using ng-model and without using id beacuse on submit how will get the id of the element.

Comment: I wouldn't use ng-model for this, and what id are you looking for? You should be able to get it via event.target